How to convert from string to decimal
We have a college project in which we need to use SSIS (as an ETL), SSMS, SQL Server, and Power BI. We have successfully loaded our dimension tables, but we encountered a problem with the fact tables. By default, in the flat file connection manager, the data type is set to 'string.'
To address this, we changed some fields (containing numbers) to 'decimal' in the flat file connection manager. In the OLE DB destination, we created a table with corresponding 'decimal' fields. However, when my friends tried to run the project on their laptops, it caused an error. Surprisingly, on my laptop, the conversion didn't cause any problems. However ,after loading the tables, I checked in SSMS and noticed that values like '41.32' became '41.00,' and '0.01' became '0.00.' I'm concerned that our Power BI dashboard won't be accurate if we don't resolve this issue. Does anyone know of any solutions?
https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1232395037002698772/1232395038105800755/image.png?ex=66294cd1&is=6627fb51&hm=2a4137bf1933f795603539d70184b6956651f009cbc00215c74fca4a32826257&=&format=webp&quality=lossless&width=1359&height=528
and this is the flat file connection manager
https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1232395037002698772/1232395037304684695/image.png?ex=66294cd1&is=6627fb51&hm=f8caa5dfbdda10c47ef1974bf6c2dd17d6032ef8f1a152d4326d1d8375948b09&=&format=webp&quality=lossless&width=667&height=578
and this is the preview of the flat file source
https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1232395037002698772/1232395037304684695/image.png?ex=66294cd1&is=6627fb51&hm=f8caa5dfbdda10c47ef1974bf6c2dd17d6032ef8f1a152d4326d1d8375948b09&=&format=webp&quality=lossless&width=597&height=517
it is difference from what I found after in the SSMS.

In the data flow task you can do a transform as a middle step between the source and destination that you do a cast/convert from 1 data type to another.

Using SSMS, right click on the fact table in question and select Script Table as Create to new window. Click Edit and paste the text of the table definition into your question.

Did you specify an explicit scale for your decimal type? If not the default is DECIMAL(18,0), which has no fractional digits.  DECLARE @Dec1 DECIMAL = 1.2345 DECLARE @Dec2 DECIMAL(18,2) = 1.2345 DECLARE @Dec3 DECIMAL(18,5) = 1.2345 SELECT @Dec1, @Dec2, @Dec3 yields "1, 1.23, 1.23450".

thank you but how to solve the rounding problem in ssms (it is rounding numbers on its own automatically)

If you multiple an int by an int you will get an int.  If you need a decimal output, you can cast both ints as decimal and then should get decimal (or put a cast around the formula to cast the results as decimal).

In connection manager column definitions, did you set the scale for the decimal types on the xxxSales columns? (The image links you posted include one link twice and omit the connection manager settings.)

what is a scale?

Scale = Number of fractional decimal places. For your data, you probably want scale = 2. (Actually called "DataScale" in tehg documentation.)

https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1232395037002698772/1232395037304684695/image.png?ex=66294cd1&is=6627fb51&hm=f8caa5dfbdda10c47ef1974bf6c2dd17d6032ef8f1a152d4326d1d8375948b09&=&format=webp&quality=lossless&width=667&height=578 here is the picture of the connection manager

https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1140713543721832618/1232423045558177792/image.png?ex=662966e7&is=66281567&hm=edcc1bbe53ed3885da3b2fe91f2274101cfd960534cf3168b77697cb16b056b3&=&format=webp&quality=lossless&width=559&height=578 here is the picture of the connection manager

Bingo! Set the DataScale value to 2 for each Sales column.

Please don't link to untrusted external resources. The question should be self contained.

(Documenting answer from discussion.)
For your "Sales" columns, make sure you have set an appropriate type, precision, and scale (DataScale) such as Decimal(18, 2) in both your target table and in the column properties of your Flat File Connection Manager.
